Laplacian of arbitrary power of arbitrary norm
So I have the function $f : \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ given by $f(x) = \lVert x \rVert_p^q$, where $\lVert \cdot \rVert_p$ denotes the $p$-norm on $\mathbb R^d$, given by
$$
\lVert x \rVert_p = \left( \sum_{i=1}^d x_i^p \right)^{1/p}.
$$
I'm looking to calculate the Laplacian of $f$, and I was able to get the follwing:
$$
\nabla^2 f(x) = q \lVert x \rVert_p^{q-p} \left((q-p)\frac{\lVert x \rVert_{2p-2}^{2p-2}}{\lVert x \rVert_{p}^{p}} + (p-1) \lVert x \rVert_{p-2}^{p-2}\right).
$$
Would someone be so kind to let me know if this expression is correct, or at least somewhat sensible? It would also be good to know if the expression can be simplified somehow. Ultimately, what I would like to undestand is how $\nabla^2 f$ is related to the Dirac delta function $\delta^d$. I could not find any good references for this given arbitrary $d$, $p$, and $q$, so any pointer to such a reference would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
